# Which control is suitable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm have a asp.net project. In `FileManager.aspx` page, I'm required to do some functions like the `somee.com` FileManager page.

Here is `FileManager` page of `somee.com`:

[image]

I want to make a table which listing all the folders,files and pages in an root folder.

In each line, I can check (in check box, expand if possible, edit if that is text file).

When I click on `doc` folder, a new page open:
[image]
I've tried for a long time, but it seems the `asp gridview` doesnt support some function that I expected.

Can you give me some advise, some document, some link to find the better way to do it.

Hope you can help !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use asp.net `tree-view` control. Here is a good exmple

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11697/ASP-NET-Tree-View-with-customized-tree-nodes

Answer (score 0):

You can use either a [tree view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4fz6xk2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) or a [nested grids](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa992038%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) with parent child relation ships for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

[Telerik - TreeList](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/treelist/examples/dataediting/net2automaticdataediting/defaultcs.aspx) is an exact match for what you want. We have used it few projects.

However, it is not free.

[image]